# 3D Array In RecyclerView To Add Image, Title, and Description To View

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created an RecyclerView with 3 properties as Image, Title, and Description. The problem is with arr[]. I'm able to set the Image only using arr[]. Here's the code:

Iside Mainactivity:

```
int []arr = {R.drawable.news,R.drawable.tag,R.drawable.rules};

main_adapter = new main_adapter(arr);
```

inside main_adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyVieHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(arr[position]);
    holder.textView.setText("Title Here");
    holder.textView1.setText("Description");
}
```

I need to set the Title and Description using the arr[] but not able to do so..

Comment: Can you move your `arr` in to `main_adapter` (which should be named `mainAdapter` - we are not using underscores in Java naming)?

Comment: Im new to Java, thanks for suggestions